# React input clear placeholder

Tags: reactjs, input, placeholder

I have a input in all the pages.
I am tryin to clear the input placeholders after send the item.name (setSearchSchool) to handleSuggestionClick. If I clear setSearchSchool in handleSuggestionClick, I am not goint to the next page. How do I clean the input placeholder?

SEARCH COMPONENT (CODE UPDATED)

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import api from "../../api/index";
import "./index.css";
import { useLocation } from "wouter";

export default function Search() {
  const [searchSchool, setSearchShool] = useState("");
  const [showSuggestions, setShowSuggestions] = useState(false);
  const [allSchools, setAllSchools] = useState([]);
  const [, pushLocation] = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const data = await api.getSchools();
      setAllSchools(data);
    })();
  }, []);

  const resultsAllSchools = !searchSchool
    ? allSchools
    : allSchools
        .map(item => ({
          name: item.name,
          codeSchool: item.codeSchool,
          address: item.address,
          city: item.city,
          nameRegion: item.nameRegion,
          codeRegion: item.codeRegion,
          latitud: item.latitud,
          longitud: item.longitud
        }))
        .filter(school => school.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchSchool));

  const handleOnchange = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const lowerCase = e.target.value.toLowerCase();
    setSearchShool(lowerCase);
    setShowSuggestions(true);
    if (e.target.value === "" || null) {
      setShowSuggestions(false);
    }
  };

  const handleSuggestionClick = item => {
    setSearchShool(item.name);
    localStorage.setItem("myLocalStore", JSON.stringify(item));
    pushLocation(`/centre/${item.codeSchool}`);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <section className="section">
        <div className="search">
          <input
            className="select"
            type="text"
            placeholder="Cerca el teu centre educatiu... "
            value={searchSchool}
            onChange={handleOnchange}
          ></input>
          <div className="svg_search">
            <svg
              height="25"
              viewBox="0 0 21 21"
              width="25"
              xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            >
              <g
                fill="none"
                fillRule="evenodd"
                stroke=" #0099ff"
                strokeWidth="2"
                strokeLinecap="round"
                strokeLinejoin="round"
              >
                <circle cx="8.5" cy="8.5" r="5" />
                <path d="m17.571 17.5-5.571-5.5" />
              </g>
            </svg>
          </div>
        </div>
        <ul>
          {showSuggestions &&
            resultsAllSchools.map((item, i) => (
              <li
                key={i}
                title={item.name}
                onClick={() => handleSuggestionClick(item)}
              >
                <p className="school_name">{item.name}</p>
                <p className="school_address">
                  {item.address} - {item.city}
                </p>
              </li>
            ))}
        </ul>
      </section>
    </>
  );
}
```

FIRTS PAGE
[image]

SECOND PAGE
[image]

Comment: why are you using so many states here? `codeSchool`, `selectSchool` and `searchSchool`, all are a single state here, all are different types of school? `codeSchool` is basically just `item.codeSchool` and searchSchool is just `item.name`. They are part of the items, they shouldn't be different state here. You could just set item in your state and derive properties from it like codeSchool and searchSchool.

Comment: You are reason I don't need codeSchool and selectSchool, thanks for the comment.  I continue have the same problem. I can't _clear the input placeholder_

Comment: update yor code above

Comment: done, code updated

Comment: You could see the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to clear out the form, then don't set the state then, use it directly from the parameters of the `handleSuggestionClick` function.

```
const handleSuggestionClick = item => {
   localStorage.setItem("myLocalStore", JSON.stringify(item));
   pushLocation(`/centre/${item.codeSchool}`);
};
```